# Confirm в цикле

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы окно confirm выскакивало, пока нажимаем "Ok"? а когда жмем "отмена", тогда только закрывалось.
Пытался сделать, но что-то он выскакивает в цикле постоянно

```
do {
    confirm("test");
} while (confirm != null);
```

Comment: а что вы именно проверяете в while условии, что за переменная, откуда у нее значение?

Comment: `while(confirm('test'));` вам надо просто

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну глядите) Давайте посмотрим на код который вы написали.

```
do {
    confirm("test");
} while (confirm != null);
```

Мы видим инструкцию

```
выполнять {
    вызвать confirm("test");
} до тех пор пока (confirm != null);
```

confirm - это метод. Он не будет равен null. Но тут проблема даже не только в этом.
Confirm показывает окошко с кнопками Ok и Cancel. Если в этом окошке вы нажимаете на OK то метод confirm **вернёт** **true**, если нажать на Cancel - то метод confirm **вернёт false**. Именно на это вам нужно опираться при проверке условия в while.

Для этого вам нужно сначала это самое true или false вернуть из confirm **и** сохранить в переменную и уже её проверять в условии.

Просто попробуйте опираясь на то что я написал выше понять этот код. Он работает:

```js
do {
  var answer = confirm("test");
} while (answer === true);
```

Comment: Обратите внимание, в этом примере я намеренно объявляю переменную с помощью устаревшего ключевого слова var (лучше вместо var использовать let или const). Я сделал так просто потому что конкретно в этой задаче так проще всего и быстрее всего. Но не привыкайте к этому ключевому слову. Лучше освойте let и const и используйте их. А если захочется решить задачку, то попробуйте ответить на вопрос почему конкретно для этой задачки я выбрал var. Удачи! :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
do {
} while(confirm("Continue?"))
```